# using elasticsearch searchtemplates in Java API

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I do not understand how to use searchTemplates in the Java API of Elasticsearch correctly. My template seems to work fine when I test it in sense. But when I use the template in Java code, it gives different results.

Here is what I do

```
DELETE /megacorp

PUT /megacorp/employee/1
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}


GET /megacorp/_search
{
  "query": {"match": {
    "about": "rock"
  }}
}
```

This returns:

```
{
  "took": 9,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.11506981,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.11506981,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So that looks nice: a score of 0.115. Now I create a searchTemplate

```
DELETE /_search/template/megacorpTemplate

POST /_search/template/megacorpTemplate
{
  "template": {
    "query": {
      "match": {
        "about": "{{txt}}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use it:

```
GET /megacorp/_search/template
{
    "id": "megacorpTemplate", 
    "params": {
        "txt":  "rock" 
    }
}
```

It returns:

```
{
  "took": 35,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.11506981,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.11506981,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So, all good and well. But now comes the problem. When I want to use this searchTemplate in my Java code, I seem to lose some information, for example the score is 1.0 and my script fields are lost (removed for brevity in this sample). Here is my code:

```
   @Test
   public void quickTest2() {
       Client client;
        try {
            client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(
                new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));


               Map<String,Object> templateParams = new HashMap<>();
               templateParams.put("txt", "rock");

               QueryBuilder tqb = QueryBuilders.templateQuery(
                        "megacorpTemplate",                  
                        ScriptService.ScriptType.INDEXED,    
                        templateParams);  

               SearchResponse searchResponse = client.prepareSearch("megacorp")
                       .setQuery(tqb)
                       .execute()
                       .actionGet(); 

               System.out.println(searchResponse.toString());


        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

It returns:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "megacorp",
      "_type" : "employee",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "first_name" : "John",
        "last_name" : "Smith",
        "age" : 25,
        "about" : "I love to go rock climbing",
        "interests" : [ "sports", "music" ]
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

So why is my score 1.0 now instead of 0.115?

Comment: If you add `.setExplain(true)` to your `prepareSearch`, what does it say? I'm guess that it is doing a constantscore query. I also think you want to 'PUT' to ' /_search/template/megacorpTemplate' instead of 'POST'

Comment: Yes, it is doing a constantscore query

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, using a Template and the setTemplate method solved my problem.

```
   @Test
   public void quickTest2() {
       Client client;
        try {
            client = TransportClient.builder().build().addTransportAddress(
                new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

               Map<String,Object> templateParams = new HashMap<>();
               templateParams.put("txt", "rock");

               Template template = new Template("megacorpTemplate", ScriptService.ScriptType.INDEXED, MustacheScriptEngineService.NAME, null, templateParams);
               SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch("megacorp").setTemplate(template);
               SearchResponse searchResponse = request.execute().actionGet();

               System.out.println(searchResponse.toString());
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```